# Integer solutions of a monic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to find integer solutions to the equation $x^3 - k^2 x +(k-1) = 0$ where $kx$ is an integer and $k > 1$. Also if there is a way to find integral solutions to the same equation if $k$ is a rational such that $k>1$.

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, consider using the Rational Root theorem - if you have a polynomial $a_n x^n + \dots + a_0$ with integer coefficients, any rational root $p/q$ to this polynomial must satisfy these properties: $q$ divides $a_n$ and $p$ divides $a_0$. You can use this to narrow down the possibilities for integer solutions to a finite set.

Comment: I was thinking of writing a program that does that , just need to figure out the ordering of the rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$The only pairs $(x,k)$, where $x$ is an integer and $k$ is rational, satisfying the equation
$$
x^3-k^2x+(k-1)=0
$$
are the pairs listed in the following table
\begin{array}
{c|c|c|c|}
x&-1&-1&0&1&1\\
\hline
k&-2&1&1&0&1\\
\end{array}
**Proof:**

The cases $x=-1,\;x=0,\;x=1$ are easily resolved, and yield the solutions from the above table.

Next suppose $(x,k)$ is a valid solution with $|x| > 1$.

Regarding the given equation as a quadratic in the variable $k$, it follows that the discriminant
$$
4x^4-4x+1
$$
must be a perfect square.

But for $|x| > 1$ we have
$$
(2x^2-1)^2 < 4x^4-4x+1 < (2x^2+1)^2
$$
so the only way for $4x^4-4x+1$ to be a perfect square is to have
$$
4x^4-4x+1 = (2x^2)^2
$$
but that would yield $x={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$,$\;$contradiction.